# Qtspim mips assembly

Tags: mips32, qtspim

When run this program the qtspim find a problem with sw command inside the procedure. What is wrong?

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter an integer: "
pinA:   .space 40  # allocate 40 bytes (10 integers * 4 bytes each)

.text
.globl main

# Subroutine to read 10 integers
read_integers:
   
    move $s1, $a0        # copy the base address of the array
    move $s2, $a1
read_loop:
    li   $v0, 4          # syscall for print string
    la   $a0, prompt     # load address of prompt
    syscall

    li   $v0, 5          # syscall for read integer
    syscall

    sw   $v0, 0($s1)      # store the read integer at the current index of the array
    addiu $s1, $s1, 4    # increment the address of the array
    addiu $s2, $s2, -1     # increment the index
    bnez  $s2, read_loop

    jr   $ra             # return to the caller

main:
    la   $a0, pinA       # load the address of the array into $a0
    li $a1, 10
    addiu $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    
    jal  read_integers   # call the subroutine

    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addiu $sp, $sp, 4
    
    # The main program continues here...
    # You can add code here to process the array or exit

    li   $v0, 10
```

## exit syscall

```
syscall
```

I would like to make a procedure to read an array of integers in MIPS32